Python with Rust: Cannot open input file python3.lib
I'm following instructions from: Maturin User Guide. I have the exact same files and contents.
But after typing: maturin develop (while being in activated venv)
I get an error:
 Found pyo3 bindings
 Found CPython 3.11 at D:\Studia\Studia\Informatyka\7 semestr\ZPR\PYTHON_RUST\guessing-game\.venv\bin\python.exe
 Using build options features from pyproject.toml
   Compiling pyo3-build-config v0.21.2
   Compiling pyo3-macros-backend v0.21.2
   Compiling pyo3-ffi v0.21.2
   Compiling pyo3 v0.21.2
   Compiling pyo3-macros v0.21.2
   Compiling guessing-game v0.1.0 (D:\Studia\Studia\Informatyka\7 semestr\ZPR\PYTHON_RUST\guessing-game)
error: linking with `link.exe` failed: exit code: 1181

  note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'python3.11.lib'


error: could not compile `guessing-game` (lib) due to 1 previous error
 maturin failed

I don't know why is this happenning, cause I have set environment variables in PATH as:
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs\
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\

And I have python3.lib in C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs\ location
Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "guessing-game"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
name = "guessing_game"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
rand = "0.8.4"

[dependencies.pyo3]
version = "0.21.2"

pyproject.toml:
[build-system]
requires = ["maturin>=1.0,<2.0"]
build-backend = "maturin"

[tool.maturin]
# "extension-module" tells pyo3 we want to build an extension module (skips linking against libpython.so)
features = ["pyo3/extension-module"]


You have python3.lib but it's looking for python3.11.lib

I'm not sure why it's looking for python3.11.lib for you. I only have python3.lib too and it works for me. Please edit your question to include your Cargo.toml and pyproject.toml

I've added it. It's the same as in tutorial

It is sometimes asking for python3.11.lib and sometimes for python3.lib

Your PATH should not include C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\… this may interfere with the wrappers from your venv

I deleted this PATH and kept the other two, but it still throws an error either "cannot open input file 'python3.11.lib'" or "python3.lib"...

You should remove all three paths (there was a … in my comment)

I deleted all three and then after "maturin develop" it still says "note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'python3.11.lib'"
